# Characterisation of the open neighbourhoods on $\infty$ on the Riemann sphere

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, proof-verification

I try to prove the following:

Let $\hat{\mathbb C}$ the Riemann sphere with the chordal metric $\hat d$. Then $U \subseteq \hat{\mathbb C}$ is an open neighbourhood of $\infty$ if and only if $U = \hat{\mathbb C} \setminus K$ for some compact set $K \subseteq \mathbb C$.

But I am a little suspicious about my solution for some reason:

"$\Rightarrow$": Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $\infty$. Then $\infty \in U$ and thus $K := \hat{\mathbb C} \setminus U \subseteq \mathbb C$ is closed. Since $\hat{\mathbb C}$ is a compact metric space it follows that $K$ is compact with respect to $\hat d$. Since the usual euclidean metric $d$ and $\hat d$ are topologically equivalent it follows that $K$ is also compact to with respect to $d$.

"$\Leftarrow$": Let $U = \hat{\mathbb C} \setminus K$ for some compact set $K \subseteq \mathbb C$. Then obviously $\infty \in U$. Further since $d$ and $\hat d$ are topologically equivalent it follows that $K$ is compact with respect to $\hat d$. Since $\hat{\mathbb C}$ is Hausdorff $K$ is closed with respect to $\hat d$ and $U =\hat{\mathbb C} \setminus K$ thus open.

Is this the right way to solve it or are there flaws in my arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite correct. The metric is not really relevant as you can see, hence this reformulation in terms of compact complements. Note that even $\infty$ is not special anymore, any point on the Riemann sphere has open neighbourhoods that have compact complement (*in the Riemann sphere*), just because we're in a compact Hausdorff space. The only thing that marks out $\infty$ is that the compact complement "lives" entirely on $\mathbb{C}$. Look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) for the general construction for locally compact Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: Every point on the Riemann sphere different from $\infty$ has open neighborhoods whose complement is not compact in $\mathbb C$. Sorry but I am afraid you are most misleading at this... point (no pun intended).

Comment: @Did I said compact, not compact in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I know what you wrote. The problem is whether what you wrote is the best possible solution for somebody asking this question.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I know about the general construction in topology but I tried to avoid using it. But thanks for validating the proof in this specific setting.